# c++ generate 2d array with O's and X's

Tags: c++

I need help trying to generate a 2D array (20x20 grid) with O's and X's. I'm later going to replace these with images to build somewhat of a map/grid. But I just need to fill them in with characters and not integers.

I have this so far:

```
    char array[20][20];

srand(time(NULL));

for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
 {
     for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {
         array[i][j]= ((rand() % 2) == 0) ? 'O' : 'X';
     }
 }
```

I don't know if that formatted right because the code thing is being weird for me, but if I have this right. How exactly do I print it out for when I run it?
I can't test it because I don't know how to print it out :/
But I feel like I have it wrong anyway.

EDIT
Then I also need to know how to swap the multidimensional array vertically... still keeping the same values/grid setup, but basically just reflecting it vertically. Not horizontally though..

Comment: That looks correct, you can print it out using std::cout << array[i][j]; inside the inner loop, then inside outer loop you can do std::cout << std::endl; for newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the generation part right. As for printing, use

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << array[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Also (for the OP's benefit) you can print the lines out as you construct them.  No need for a separate loop.

Comment: Do you know how you would flip that around now? xD Keeping the same letters and everything?? Like how you would flip it on it's vertical axis?

Comment: In place of `"\n"` at the end I'd use `std::endl` but maybe that's being ridiculously ridiculous.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: Why endl? It flushes the stream which makes no sense for std::cout since it is tied with std::cin

Comment: That will still make it randomly generate the columns though... I need to put it all within the same loop I would think since if I create another for loop, it will randomly generate another set of columns which won't be the same as the first loop..

Comment: @Peanut: I really don't understand what you mean and it's 4 AM here, so I'm going to bed now :)

Comment: @Armen: Doesn't "\n" typically trigger a flush too on stdout?  I use `endl` because it's a symbolic constant of sorts and I like those.

Comment: How exactly do I "swap" the loops? generating another for loop will generate a whole other set of random letters.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: On the contrary, `std::endl` flushes, not `"\n"` and it's not a constant, it's a stream manipulator. endl basically streams '\n' to the stream and calls flush.